# Finding sublists inside lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list that may or may not contain sublists as elements, and I need to check  whether an element is or is not a sublist.

For example consider

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'] ]
```

As I would expect, I get

```
>>> list[2]
'c'
>>> list[3]
['d', 'e']
>>> list[3][1]
'e'
```

and

```
>>> len(list[1])
1
>>> len(list[3])
2
```

and also

```
>>> type(list[1])
<type 'str'>
>>> type(list[3])
<type 'list'>
```

So far so good. However, quite surprisingly (at least for a python novice as I am)

```
>>> type(list[1]) is list
False
>>> type(list[3]) is list
False
```

Could somebody explain this? Clearly I can just use `len()` to determine whether an element is a sublist, but I think the explicit type checking should be more appropriate, as it is a more precise statement of what I want to do. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you could use `len()`. If your list was `['ab','cd','ef']` then every element would have length > 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the name `list` and are *shadowing the built-in*.

As such you are testing if the type of one element *in* your list is the same object as the list itself.

Rename your list to not use the same name:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'] ]
>>> type(lst[3])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(lst[3]) is list
True
```

Generally speaking, you want to use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test if something is a list:

```
>>> isinstance(lst[3], list)
True
```

Comment: Ah ah, I can't believe I was so dumb! Downvotes well deserved!

Answer (score 0):

simply check if element is a list:

```
def is_inside(my_list, elem):
    if isinstance(my_list, list):
        return any([is_inside(child, elem) for child in my_list])
    else:
        return my_list == elem

In: is_inside(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']], 'e')
Out: True

In: is_inside(['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']], 'f')
Out: False
```

Comment: I think you've misread the question. This isn't what OP was trying to do.